# Why is bower not using my bower.json resolutions?

Tags: angularjs, bower

I have a project I need to use angularjs 1.2 with. I have a bower.json file with the following:

```
{
  "name": "myproject",
  "dependencies": {
    "angular": "1.2.32"
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "angular": "1.2.32"
  }
}
```

When I install angular it asks me which version I want, although it should not if I understood correctly. And when I try to install another project like angular-route it asks again and even installs the wrong one:

```
bower install angular-route
bower angular-route#*           cached https://github.com/angular/bower-angular-route.git#1.6.4
bower angular-route#*         validate 1.6.4 against https://github.com/angular/bower-angular-route.git#*
bower angular#1.6.4             cached https://github.com/angular/bower-angular.git#1.6.4
bower angular#1.6.4           validate 1.6.4 against https://github.com/angular/bower-angular.git#1.6.4

Unable to find a suitable version for angular, please choose one by typing one of the numbers below:
    1) angular#1.2.32 which resolved to 1.2.32 and is required by angamcharts2
    2) angular#1.6.4 which resolved to 1.6.4 and is required by angular-route#1.6.4

Prefix the choice with ! to persist it to bower.json

? Answer !1
bower angular               resolution Saved angular#1.2.32 as resolution
bower angular-route#^1.6.4     install angular-route#1.6.4

angular-route#1.6.4 bower_components/angular-route
└── angular#1.2.32
```

I know there is angular-route 1.2.32 but I don't want to install all my packages by hand with the correct version. Why is the "resolutions" not working?